# Trial apps in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8

In WinPhone 8 SDK, there are two `LicenseInformation` classes:

- Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation (present since WP7.0)
- Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.LicenseInformation (WinRT-inspired)

And two ways to initiate a full product purchase:

- via `MarketplaceDetailTask` with app GUID as `ContentIdentifier`
- via `CurrentApp.RequestAppPurchaseAsync`

They're slightly different. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the guidelines available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967558(v=vs.105).aspx (Updated link for WP8)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286402(v=vs.105).aspx (Updated link for wP8)

You should use MarketplaceDetailTask with the Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation class.

Comment: "v.92" docs are for WP7, not WP8. WP8 docs on MSDN are tagged as "v.105".

Comment: Hi, is there any API for native c++ WP8 applications?